# Configure Gson in Spring before using GsonHttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gson

How to configure [Gson](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) before constructing a [GsonHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/GsonHttpMessageConverter.html)?

I need to use [@Expose](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) and specify Date format.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## (New Method) Using Java Config

Extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` or if you need more control use `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(createGsonHttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    private GsonHttpMessageConverter createGsonHttpMessageConverter() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
                .create();

        GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        gsonConverter.setGson(gson);

        return gsonConverter;
    }

}
```

You can read more on how to [customize provided configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-customize).

## (Old Method) Using XML configuration

In DispatcherServlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="gsonBuilder" class="com.google.gson.GsonBuilder">
        <property name="dateFormat" value="yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="gsonBuilder" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="gson">
                    <bean class="com.google.gson.Gson" factory-bean="gsonBuilder" factory-method="create" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

</beans>
```

Comment: I think `class="com.google.gson.Gson"` is not needed inside gson bean as you have specified `factory-bean` property.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sometimes I like to be verbose and explicit =)

Comment: oops I misread something, anyway class part is confusing because it's not clear whether a class or bean is used in construction I had to look up into documentation which specifies what overrides what. In my version I just used a static class `<bean class="org.my.StaticGsonBuilder" factory-method="build" />` with `public static Gson build(){}` method of `StaticGsonBuilder` class

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdaptor is deprecated. Now implement WebMvcConfigurer

Comment: @JMess, is a class name the only thing that changed?

Comment: Yes, looks like they kept the method names the same. [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html)