# Configuring snake_case query parameter using Gson in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, gson

I try to configure Gson as my JSON mapper to accept "snake_case" query parameter, and translate them into standard Java "camelCase" parameters.

First of all, I know I could use the `@SerializedName` annotation to customise the serialized name of each field, but this will involve some manual work.

After doing some search, I believe the following approach should work (please correct me if I am wrong).

1. Use Gson as the default JSON mapper of Spring Boot

`spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson`

2. Configuring Gson before `GsonHttpMessageConverter` is created [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335146/configure-gson-in-spring-before-using-gsonhttpmessageconverter)
3. Customising the Gson naming policy in step 2 according to [GSON Field Naming Policy](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html)

```java
private GsonHttpMessageConverter createGsonHttpMessageConverter() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                   .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                   .create();

    GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    gsonConverter.setGson(gson);

    return gsonConverter;
}
```

Then I create a simple controller like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/gson-naming-policy")
public Object testNamingPolicy(ExampleParam data) {
    return data.getCamelCase();
}
```

With the following `Param` class:

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ExampleParam {

    private String camelCase;

}
```

But when I call the controller with query parameter `?camel_case=hello`, the `data.camelCase` could not been populated (and it's null). When I change the query parameters to `?camelCase=hello` then it could be set, which mean my setting is not working as expected.

Any hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nice question. If I understand how Spring MVC works behind the scenes, no HTTP converters are used for `@ModelAttribute`-driven. It can be inspected easily when throwing an exception from your `ExampleParam` constructor or the `ExampleParam.setCamelCase` method (de-Lombok first) -- Spring uses its bean utilities that use `public` (!) `ExampleParam.setCamelCase` to set the DTO value. Another proof is that no `Gson.fromJson` is never invoked regardless how your Gson converter is configured. So, your `camelCase` confuses you because the default Gson instance uses this strategy as well as Spring does -- so this is just a matter of confusion.

In order to make it work, you have to create a custom Gson-aware `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` implementation. Let's assume we support POJO only (not lists, maps or primitives).

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcConfiguration
        extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .create();

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new HandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
            @Override
            public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
                // It must be never a primitive, array, string, boxed number, map or list -- and whatever you configure ;)
                final Class<?> parameterType = parameter.getParameterType();
                return !parameterType.isPrimitive()
                        && !parameterType.isArray()
                        && parameterType != String.class
                        && !Number.class.isAssignableFrom(parameterType)
                        && !Map.class.isAssignableFrom(parameterType)
                        && !List.class.isAssignableFrom(parameterType);
            }

            @Override
            public Object resolveArgument(final MethodParameter parameter, final ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, final NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                    final WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
                // Now we're deconstructing the request parameters creating a JSON tree, because Gson can convert from JSON trees to POJOs transparently
                // Also note parameter.getGenericParameterType() -- it's better that Class<?> that cannot hold generic types parameterization
                return gson.fromJson(
                        parameterMapToJsonElement(webRequest.getParameterMap()),
                        parameter.getGenericParameterType()
                );
            }
        });
    }

    ...

    private static JsonElement parameterMapToJsonElement(final Map<String, String[]> parameters) {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        for ( final Entry<String, String[]> e : parameters.entrySet() ) {
            final String key = e.getKey();
            final String[] value = e.getValue();
            final JsonElement jsonValue;
            switch ( value.length ) {
            case 0:
                // As far as I understand, this must never happen, but I'm not sure
                jsonValue = JsonNull.INSTANCE;
                break;
            case 1:
                // If there's a single value only, let's convert it to a string literal
                // Gson is good at "weak typing": strings can be parsed automatically to numbers and booleans
                jsonValue = new JsonPrimitive(value[0]);
                break;
            default:
                // If there are more than 1 element -- make it an array
                final JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
                for ( int i = 0; i < value.length; i++ ) {
                    jsonArray.add(value[i]);
                }
                jsonValue = jsonArray;
                break;
            }
            jsonObject.add(key, jsonValue);
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

}
```

So, here are the results:

- `http://localhost:8080/?camelCase=hello` => *(empty)*
- `http://localhost:8080/?camel_case=hello` => `"hello"`

Comment: Work perfectly! `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is a blind zone for me. May I know what clues might lead me to this resolver (if without your help)?

Comment: @Wenzhong Sorry, I seem to have confused you with "behind the scenes" (actually while peeking into my codebase): `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is a standard well-known Spring MVC interface used very often.

Comment: Thank you @lyubomyr-shaydariv !  Still a lot to learn for me.

Comment: one more problem encountered, may I know which resolver I should check if I also want to set @PathParam into the ExampleParam? i.e. http://localhost:8080/resource/:resource_id?camel_case=hello  .  And I want to access both `resourceId` and `camelCase` inside the ExampleParam

Comment: Further more, is it possible to merge `@RequestBody` / `@PathParam` / `@Param` into `ExampleParam` ?

Comment: @Wenzhong I guess yes: you have enough information on controller methods signatures, parameters, etc. However I have no clue if it's possible to combine a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` with the built-in resolvers provided by Spring.