# Recreate DTO class without field property instead of having it null using Gson/Jackson and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, gson

I have a DTO class that returns this:

```
{
  "id": "fdbfb1ec-1f1e-4867-9cc8-73929fbcc07e",
  "title": "My another category",
  "reports": null
}
```

When I actually would like for some of my api calls to have the reports key as not part of it as per the below, rather than being set to null.

```
{
  "id": "fdbfb1ec-1f1e-4867-9cc8-73929fbcc07e",
  "title": "My another category",
}
```

I tried to use Gson and Expose annotation believing this would remove my key, but it just seems to be turning it to null instead. I tried both using `@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)` or leaving it without the annotation since my Gson object uses the `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` piece but both give me the same outcome. However, I can see  my string converter excludes the reports key and gives me this `{"id":"fdbfb1ec-1f1e-4867-9cc8-73929fbcc07e","title":"My another category"}` but not sure why the property is still there when the object is recreated and if the only solution for this scenario would not be through Gson but have two complete different DTOs instead, one with that property and the other without it?

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CategoryQueryDto {

    @Expose()
    private UUID id;
    @Expose()
    private String title;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private List<ReportQueryDto> reports;

    public CategoryQueryDto(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public CategoryQueryDto(UUID id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

}


@Override
public CategoryQueryDto getCategory(UUID id) {

    if (categoryRepository.findById(id).isPresent()) {
        Category category = categoryRepository.findById(id).get();

        CategoryQueryDto categoryQueryDto = new CategoryQueryDto(category.getId(), category.getTitle());

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        String converter = gson.toJson(categoryQueryDto);

        categoryQueryDto = gson.fromJson(converter, CategoryQueryDto.class);


        return categoryQueryDto;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Thank you very much.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is my code on Github https://github.com/francislainy/gatling_tool_backend

Tried with Jackson rather than Gson and got the same issue.

Comment: That sounds rather weird, especially since Gson should by default not even serialize `null` fields (see [`GsonBuilder.serializeNulls()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeNulls())). Could it be that Lombok (whose annotations you are apparently using) is somehow interfering with Gson? What happens when you remove the annotations (for testing)? Also what is the purpose of your `getCategory(...)` method? It looks like it is serializing and then immediately deserializing the object again.

Comment: Hi @Marcono1234, thanks for your comment. I've tried now removing all the lombok from my project and doing normal constructors and getters and setters but I'm afraid I got the same result. Here is my code on Github if you or someone else may be able to have a look and point me to what I may be doing wrong. I'm very newbie to Spring and not really sure what else to try. https://github.com/francislainy/gatling_tool_backend

Comment: ```Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        String converter = gson.toJson(categoryQueryDto);

        categoryQueryDto = gson.fromJson(converter, CategoryQueryDto.class);```

Comment: About your question, is this the part you're referring to? Yeah, that's me trying to json and then back to the class object forcefully going through gson to see if that would work.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Spring Framework, so the following might be completely wrong, but maybe it helps nonetheless. It appears Spring Boot is using Jackson by default for JSON serialization. So you would either have to [configure Jackson](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-message-converters) or [specify that Gson is used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31335147).

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'm more familiar with Gson but can try with Jackson instead and see if it makes any difference. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I tried now with Jackson too but got the same issue still. :(

Comment: In your repository is commit `7075b80f` where you tried Jackson? If I understand this part of Spring correctly it is doing the conversion on its own, your conversion to and from JSON within the method has no effect. After all in your code you are discarding the JSON value and returning a `CategoryQueryDto`. It looks like you have to configure the serialization as shown in the links above.

Comment: Okay, yeah, if Jackson is already the default that would make sense and I may not need those extra lines to convert to and from it, but I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand what to do with the links above as if that's the case why would I still need to configure Jackson.

Comment: If Jackson is indeed the default and you don't want the `null` to appear in your JSON you would have to configure it. Maybe adding the [jackson] tag to this question would help so someone familiar with it can suggest how to solve this.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the Jackson tag now if that may attract someone familiar with it to try and help solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on the field I wanted to show only if not null and it worked.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CategoryQueryDto {

@Expose()
private UUID id;
@Expose()
private String title;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private List<ReportQueryDto> reports = null;

public CategoryQueryDto(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public CategoryQueryDto(UUID id, String title) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
}

}
```

And here my controller with Jackson

```
@Service
public class CategoryQueryServiceImpl implements CategoryQueryService {

@Autowired
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@Autowired
private ReportRepository reportRepository;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public CategoryQueryDto getCategory(UUID id) throws JsonProcessingException {

    if (categoryRepository.findById(id).isPresent()) {
        Category category = categoryRepository.findById(id).get();

        CategoryQueryDto categoryQueryDto = new CategoryQueryDto(category.getId(), category.getTitle());

        
        String converter = mapper.writeValueAsString(categoryQueryDto);

        categoryQueryDto = mapper.readValue(converter, CategoryQueryDto.class);


        return categoryQueryDto;


    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

POM

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.13</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Opening a question on the Gson equivalent for this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105969/gson-equivalent-to-jsonincludejsoninclude-include-non-null